# doubts about unit testing DAOs

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, dao, easymock

I am looking for information to build unit test for typical DAO methods (find user by username, etc.) and I found several examples using mocks like this one: http://www.christophbrill.de/de_DE/unit-testing-with-junit-and-mockito/

```
@Test
public void testComeGetSome() {
    // Mock the EntityManager to return our dummy element
    Some dummy = new Some();
    EntityManager em = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
    Mockito.when(em.find(Some.class, 1234)).thenReturn(dummy);

    // Mock the SomeDao to use our EntityManager
    SomeDao someDao = Mockito.mock(SomeDao.class);
    Mockito.when(someDao.comeGetSome(1234)).thenCallRealMethod();
    Mockito.when(someDao.getEntityManager()).thenReturn(em);

    // Perform the actual test
    Assert.assertSame(dummy, someDao.comeGetSome(1234));
    Assert.assertNull(someDao.comeGetSome(4321));
}
```

There is also a similar one in Lasse Koskela's book using EasyMock instead of Mockito.

The thing is: what are we really testing in these examples? We are basically telling through mocks what object the query should return, and then asserting that in fact it returned the object we told it to return.

We are not testing if the query is correct or if it returns a different object or no objects at all (or even more than one object). We cannot test if it returns null when the object does not exist in the database. This line

```
Assert.assertNull(someDao.comeGetSome(4321));
```

works because there is no scripted interaction for that argument, not because the object does not exist.

It looks like we are just testing if the method calls the proper methods and objects (em.find).

What is the point of unit testing this? Are there any good frameworks in Java to quickly set up an in memory database and perform tests with it?

Comment: Friday blues it seems. The mockup is made to return a specific value on a specific query. Testing just that is of course ridiculous. However testing business logic that uses DAO queries will then be possible. _Reminds me of counting sheep not twice by clubbing every counted sheep._

Comment: This is a topic constantly I am concerned, generally someone in the office comes to tell me "we need to write Junit tests", and I always reply "what do you want to test", people generally are confused about unit test on the db layer and the application layer, so, I write mostly code for the application layer and mock data coming from DB, but if you really want to write DAO test cases with in memory db then I would suggest to use H2 (http://www.h2database.com) or HyperSQL (http://hsqldb.org/)

Comment: What you are doing, is nothing but a nonsense. If you want to test DAO layer, you perform integration tests. You never mock method behavior that is about to be tested.

Comment: Then if I understand your comments you agree with me, and these methods, usually found in session facades, service facades, DAOs or whatever you call it, should not be unit tested.
As I understand it, using a quick replica of the database makes then integration tests...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your doubts really make sense. Actually there is no need to test DAO with unit tests in most cases because unit tests deal with one layer, but DAO cooperate with database layer.

This article explains this idea:
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/writing-tests-for-data-access-code-unit-tests-are-waste/

Hence we should test DAO and database layer with integration tests.
Integration tests take into account both DAO and database layer.

This article will provide your with Spring + Hibernate example:
https://dzone.com/articles/easy-integration-testing

Answer (score 1):

It looks loke more like service tests, than a real DAO tests.
For example, I'm using `dbunit` to test my DAO layer.

For example, I have `Author` table with 2 fields: `id` and `name`.
I'm creating a dataset xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <AUTHOR AUTHOR_ID="1" NAME="FirstAuthor"/>
    ...
    <AUTHOR AUTHOR_ID="10" NAME="TenthAuthor"/>
</dataset>
```

And then in my test class using `Mockito` I'm testing my DAO methods like

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup(value = "/dao/author/author-data.xml")
public void testFindAll() {
    List<Author> authorList = this.authorDAO.findAll();
    assertEquals(10, authorList.size());
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this?, the test case does not give so much value, See the comments to the question.

Comment: I guess that xml dataset should mimic the real database, so the same query we are testing shuld work for both.